# Using Google Assistant SDK

Tags: android, ios, google-assistant-sdk

1. Is it possible to use text-based queries and responses in Assistant SDK in Android/iOS app?
2. Could responses be parsed as a text?
3. Is it possible to use certain Google account/user context while using Assistant SDK? Guess it could be useful for Assistant to know who exactly asks the questions. So it going to looks like a user asks Assistant, but actually the app does it.
   Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant

Answer (score 1):

1,2. Yes part of the API includes text input and text responses
3. Users must authenticate, so you will have a refresh token
3. You can register custom device actions in order trigger custom grammars that you've set.

Comment: But what about using Assistant SDK in iOS?

Comment: It's a grpc API. It would be the same for any platform.